# Adding a list of objects to a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, object, dictionary, key

EDIT: This issue has been resolved. I guess I'll just leave this here for any future persons who need an example.

This code takes in an input file, parses through it, passes the file to a class, stores the objects in a dictionary, and then writes out the objects in the specified format. Have any questions? I would be happy to answer them!

Here is my code:

```
#C:\Python27\python.exe Animals(1).py

inp = open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\Classes\ClassTutorialInput.txt", "r")
outp = open("C:\Users\curnutte\Desktop\Assignment\Python Scripts\Python example\Classes\ClassTutorialOutput.txt", "w")

aniList = []

for line in inp.readlines():
    if line == '\n':
        line = "nothing"
    line = line.strip()                                                        #removes '\n'
    if line != '%% ================= %%':                                       #grabs all pertinent information
        aniList.append(line)                                                    #condenses lines to one line
print(aniList)

class Animals():                                                                 #creates the Animals class
    def __init__(self, species, features, diet, drinks, threats):
        self.species = species
        self.features = features
        self.diet = diet
        self.drinks = drinks
        self.threats = threats

my_animals=[]

counter = 0
for item in aniList:                                                            #iterates through the input file
    counter += 1
    if counter == 1:
        species = item
        continue
    if counter == 2:
        features = item
        continue
    if counter == 3:
        diet = item
        continue
    if counter == 4:
        drinks = item
        continue
    if counter == 5:
        threats = item
        my_animals.append(Animals(species, features, diet, drinks, threats))
        counter = 0
        continue

animal_dict = {}

for index in my_animals:
    animal_dict[index.species] = (index)
    print (animal_dict)
    oldLook = index.features.split(",")
    newLook = index.features
    if len(oldLook) == 2:
        newLook = oldLook[0].strip() + ' and ' + oldLook[1].strip()
    if len(oldLook) > 2:
        newLook = oldLook[:-1]
        newLook = ",".join(newLook)
        newLook = newLook + ' and ' + oldLook[-1].strip()
    index.features = newLook

    oldDiet = index.diet.split(",")
    newDiet = index.diet
    if len(oldDiet) == 2:
        newDiet = oldDiet[0].strip() + ' and ' + oldDiet[1].strip()
    if len(oldDiet) > 2:
        newDiet = oldDiet[:-1]
        newDiet = ",".join(newDiet)
        newDiet = newDiet + ' and ' + oldDiet[-1].strip()
    index.diet = newDiet

    oldPred = index.threats.split(",")
    newPred = index.threats
    if len(oldPred) == 2:
       newPred = oldPred[0].strip() + ' and ' + oldPred[1].strip()
    if len(oldPred) > 2:
       newPred = oldPred[:-1]
       newPred = ",".join(newPred)
       newPred = newPred + ' and ' + oldPred[-1].strip()
    index.threats = newPred
    outp.write("A %s has %s, eats %s, drinks %s, and is eaten by %s.\n" % (index.species, index.features, index.diet, index.drinks, index.threats))

inp.close()
outp.close()
```

Here is 'ClassTutorialInput.txt':

```
deer
fur, antlers, a peaceful disposition
grass, leaves, roots
water
wolves, bear, mountain lions
%% ================= %%
fish
scales, a clueless lifestyle
bugs
water
sharks, humans
%% ================= %%
lion
fur, manes, a blood-thirst
antelope, humans
water

%% ================= %%
human
hair, skin
vegetables, meat
water

%% ================= %%
```

Comment: Try removing extra parenthesis in the print statements. Change `print((Bambi.species, Bambi.features, Bambi.diet, Bambi.threats))` to `print(Bambi.species, Bambi.features, Bambi.diet, Bambi.threats)`

Comment: That does clean things up a bit! But, how can I write the input file out as three strings, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index in my_animals:
oldDiet = index.diet.split(",")
newDiet = index.diet
if len(oldDiet) == 2:
    newDiet = oldDiet[0].strip() + ' and ' + oldDiet[1].strip()
if len(oldDiet) > 2:
    newDiet = oldDiet[:-1]
    newDiet = ",".join(newDiet)
    newDiet = newDiet + ' and ' + oldDiet[-1].strip()
index.diet = newDiet

oldPred = index.threats.split(",")
newPred = index.threats
if len(oldPred) == 2:
    newPred = oldPred[0].strip() + ' and ' + oldPred[1].strip()
if len(oldPred) > 2:
    newPred = oldPred[:1]
    newPred = ",".join(newPred)
    newPred = newPred + ' and ' + oldPred[-1].strip()
index.threats = newPred
outp.write("A %s has %s, eats %s, and is eaten by %s.\n" % (index.species, index.features, index.diet, index.threats))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the lines in your input file by adding the line: `input_lines = inp.readlines()` which will return a list of all of the lines in your input file which you can then parse.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I've used this line and have now accessed the input file. Now I just need to figure out what sort of criteria to place on the file. I'm assuming I will need for loops and if statements.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions as to how to approach this?